# Need regex for matching one or more character groups

Tags: regex

I have a requirement for a regular expression for the following conditions.

1. It should allow only alphabets (both cases)
2. It should not allow only numbers or only special characters. i.e, combination of atleast two or more of the following character sets (numbers,alphabets,special characters).

Eg:
`abcsfdASDFASFasdf`----Valid

`1234523562354`---Invalid

`~!@#$&*!!!`----Invalid

`asdfbsdf1234`---valid

`123454~!@~~~#%^`---valid

`abfasf1234123!~!@#$@!`---valid.

Comment: This question reeks of "I've tried nothing and I'm all out of ideas"...

Comment: Looks like forcing some password constrains on the poor user, bad idea... (related: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/password_strength.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will check for all the four options:

https://www.regex101.com/r/cP2lS0/1

```
 ((?=.*[A-Za-z]).*)|((?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d).*)|((?=.*[@#$%])(?=.*\d).*)
```

Explanation:

`((?=.*[A-Za-z]).*)` - alphabets (only or with other group)

`((?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d).*)` - numbers and alphabets

`((?=.*[@#$%])(?=.*\d).*)` - special chars and numbers

Comment: Thanks griffon, great !! it is working as expected.... Thanks again for your time...

Answer (score 0):

I think you could improve on this...

```
([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)|([a-zA-Z]+[-!@#$%^&*_]+)|([0-9]+[-!@#$%^&*_]+)
```

1. letters or nums
2. letter or special chars
3. numbers or letters

You could also use 3 flags and create regex seperately:
One for atleast 1 digit,
 one for atleast 1 letter
 and one  for atleast 1 special character 
Then write if else statements to make sure atleast 2 of the regexes evalueate to true.